# Any way to always send HHVM all request to same file in server mode (not FastCGI)?

Tags: php, nginx, hhvm

Working setup, assume a request to  `http://127.0.0.1:8080/path/to/resource`:

- nginx/apache receives the request and passes it to index.php behind the scenes to hhvm vi FastCGI.
- After the the handoff via FastCGI, the `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` is always `index.php` and the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is from the url `/path/to/resource` (notice, no `index.php` anywhere in it)
- I've got a framework with an `index.php` file in /some/path/public/index.php
- All requests go to `index.php` and have their URI's (in this case `/path/to/resource) parsed by a routing system.
- The actual code handling the request have no structural relation in form to the URI (i.e. there's no /path/to/resource/index.php)

In order to take nginx or apache out of the picture when running hhvm for dev purposes or just fun, I run hhvm in server mode (**NOT FastCGI mode!!!**):

```
cd /some/path/public/
hhvm -m server -p 8080
```

However, the framework doesn't handle the `index.php` in the path gracefully.  When served by hhvm running in server mode the only urls that work are:

```
 http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.php
 ...or...
 http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

Anything more complex fails like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/path/to/resource  (HHVM fails, file not found)
```

Also, sticking in an explicit index.php fails as the framework doesn't handle the `index.php` in the `REQUEST_URI` gracefully.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.php/path/to/resource  (HHVM works, but framework fails, `index.php` in uri confuses it)
```

Does anyone know a way to get this to work where ALL request are sent to the root /some/path/public/index.php?   Is there an option to set the SCRIPT_NAME explicitly via a option flag/setting?

Ideally the request `http://127.0.0.1:8080/path/to/resource` would have:

- SCRIPT_NAME = `index.php`
- REQUEST_URI = `/path/to/resource`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured a few ways, running HHVM 3.18.1 with some help from another SO user.

The best way is to use virtual hosts rewite rules:

```
hhvm.server.default_document = index.php

hhvm.virtual_host[default][rewrite_rules][common][pattern] = "(.*)"
hhvm.virtual_host[default][rewrite_rules][common][to] = "index.php/$1"
hhvm.virtual_host[default][rewrite_rules][common][qsa] = true
```

Had a hard time finding documentation on this, but here's a link to the HHVM docs sort of explaining:  https://docs.hhvm.com/hhvm/configuration/INI-settings#server-mode__virtual-host-format

Note that the documentation is the old format, not the new `ini` format, so option names should be converted from `CamelCase` to underscore seperated like `camel_case`.

**Another, less elegant way:**
Without using rewrites, you can hijack 404's.  You need to set **BOTH** the parameters

- `hhvm.server.error_document404`
- `hhvm.server.default_document`

Set both of these to whatever your default index/routing file is--let your framework handle 404 messages.

You can set these in an `ini` config file (I'll call it `server.ini`):

```
 hhvm.server.default_document = /path/to/index.php
 hhvm.server.error_document404 = /path/to/index.php
```

Then you can start the server with:

```
 hhvm -m server  -p 8080  -c /path/to/server.ini
```

You can also skip the INI file and pass the details in when starting HHVM:

```
 hhvm -m server -p 8080 -d  hhvm.server.default_document=/path/to/index.php -d hhvm.server.error_document404=/path/to/index.php
```

If you don't want to have to run `hhvm` from a specific folder, you can also set:

```
hhvm.server.source_root=/path/to/doc_root
```

**Notes:**

- If this is set the `default_document` and `error_document404` will be relative to this directory unless they have fully qualified paths.  However, you must set the `error_document404` to something explicitly.  While `default_document` seems to default to `index.php`, the `error_document404` seems not to have a default value.
- Explicitly including index.php in the url (unless it's alone) fails.  This means: `http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.php/path/to/resource` fails but   `http://127.0.0.1:8080/path/to/resource` now works.  Guess you can't have your cake and eat it too :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento thanks, makes much more sense.  Was finally able to locate some of the documentation for the hhvm virtual host options given text from your question.  I'm updating my answer based on your post.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento also if you add your solution as an answer, I'll pick it.

Answer (score 0):

As of HHVM 4.26, you can use the [hhvm.server.global_document](https://docs.hhvm.com/hhvm/configuration/INI-settings) setting in server.ini.

An example would be:

```
hhvm.server.global_document = index.hh
```

All requests will now go through index.hh